# vertical-align:middle a div inside a floating div?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

Why doesn't the  black stripe in column three vertical-align in the middle of the parent div? Instead in aligns a little below the top. Is there a way to fix it?

https://jsfiddle.net/pr1v6Lhd/4/

HTML:

```
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>ADMIN<br>:(</td>
      <td>222387</td>
      <td width='50' style='position:relative'>
        <div class='data'>59853.94</div>
        <div class="bar-chart-bar">
          <div class="bar" style='width:50%; background-color:#B8E4F5'>
          <div style="height:10px; background-color:black; width:100%;vertical-align:middle; display: inline-block"></div>            
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td width="50">0</td>
      <td>59853.94</td>
      <td>4189.82</td>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.bar-chart-bar {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.bar {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}

.data {

}

.table > tbody > tr > td {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

table {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your `.bar` class, you can add

```
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
justify-content:center;
```

as well as remove

```
vertical-align: middle;
display: inline-block;
```

from your `.data` class. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/pr1v6Lhd/6/) is the result.   The reason this wasn't working for you is that `vertical-align` doesn't really behave the way you want it to unless your element is in a table cell. See [this](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html) for more about vertical align.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Flex is something new in CSS3? Can it be a problem with older browsers like IE9?

Comment: @stee1rat that would cause problems (see browser compatibility [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)). There are a few ways to work around it, depending on whether or not `.data` a fixed height. Use [this](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) and open up `vertically` > `Is it a block-level element?`

Answer (score 1):

In this case `vertical-align` for `inline-block` elements works in relation to other elements not to the container itself, you can add a reference element like this:

```
.bar:before {
  content:"";
  display:inline-block;
  height:100%;
  margin-right:-4px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

#### [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pr1v6Lhd/5/)

Comment: Could you, please, explain what element does it work in relation to in my case? I set it as an inline-block because it was the only thing that worked somehow..

Comment: in your case doesn't have any sibling elements to be vertical positioned, adding a pseudo-element with 100% height now can be middle aligned @stee1rat